# Does playing Costume Quest on Halloween (Oct 31st) do anything different?

Tags: costume-quest

It just occurred to me, but is there anything different in *Costume Quest* when actually playing on Halloween (Oct 31)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never heard anything about it! It could have been extremely good idea for cons!

If I rely on the [official website](http://www.costumequestgame.com), no relative information to your question is written.